# Layer events loading GeoJSON feature geometries using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, events

I am using Leaflet 1.7.1.

I want to add simple tooltips to poly-layer after they are constructed. I tried everything. External `onEachFeature()` function `featureGroup`. But it seems that events the layers are not triggered. With the legacy Version, it is functioning. Here is the code. Styles are applied and the `onEachFeature()` function is executed.

Where is my problem?

```
plz.postcodes = L.geoJSON(data, {
                style: function (feature) {
                    return {
                        color: 'yellow',
                        fillColor: 'black',
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: 1,
                        fillOpacity: 0.1
                    };
                },
                onEachFeature: function(feature,layer) {
                    console.log(feature.properties.plz);
                    layer.on({
                        mouseover: function (e) {
                            console.log(e.target);
                        },
                        mouseout: function () {
                            plz.map.closeTooltip();
                        },
                    });
                }
            }).addTo(plz.map);
```

Comment: Found the solution. I forgot to change the CSS from the old legacy version to the new version. It seems that tooltip and popups are invisible with the CSS.

Answer (score -1):

All layers in Leaflet have `.bindTooltip` method (see Tooltip methods section in https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layer). It takes care of opening tooltip on `mouseover` and closing it on `mouseout`.

If your desired tooltip content is `feature.properties.plz`, then relevant part of the code would look something like this:

```
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.plz);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ... I already tried this. It seems to me that the svg in the overlay pane is visible but events are not triggered. I already tried to change the z-index.

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: And what do you mean by "svg in the overlay pane is visible"? That GeoJSON features are visible?